# Meaning of pullback functor in a particular setting

Tags: logic, category-theory, notation, type-theory

In Definition B.2.1 of the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.2851.pdf, the authors state a so-called stability condition:
$$f^{*}(\boldsymbol{\pi}(a, b))=\boldsymbol{\pi}\left(f^{*} a, f^{*} b\right)$$ where $f: \Gamma' \to \Gamma$.

Here, $a: \Gamma \longrightarrow U$,  $b:\left(\Gamma, a^{*}{El}\right) \longrightarrow U$, and  $\boldsymbol{\pi}(a, b): \Gamma \longrightarrow U$.

I can't understand how the pullback functor $f^{\ast}$ is acting on $\boldsymbol{\pi}$, $a$, or $b$. It doesn't seem to me that any of these maps is a morphism in the correct slice category. Any ideas?

Comment: $f^\ast a$ stands for $f^\ast$ applied to the projection $(\Gamma,a^\ast \mathrm{El})\to \Gamma$ or equivalently it stands for the projection $(\Gamma',(af)^\ast\mathrm{El})$. The same applies to the notation $f^\ast \pi(a,b)$. As for $f^\ast b$, it stands for $f^\ast$ applied to an arrow of the slice over $\Gamma$, namely $(\Gamma,a^\ast\mathrm{El},b^\ast\mathrm{El}) \to (\Gamma,a^\ast\mathrm{El})$.

Comment: All that is harmless because a universe $(\mathrm{El},U)$ establishes a bijection $(a:\Gamma\to U) \mapsto (p_{((\Gamma,a^\ast\mathrm{El}))}:(\Gamma,a^\ast\mathrm{El}) \to \Gamma)$, natural in $\Gamma$. Which somehow seems to be missing in the definition of a universe in the linked article. Maybe it can be inferred from the other parts of the paper that I just glimsed over. (That is why I'm not making that an answer, I might have missed something here.)

Comment: @Pece I think that bijection just comes from the fact that all canonical pullbacks (i.e., pullbacks of the projection morphisms $p$) exist by definition of a contextual category.

Comment: I was not worried about the existence of the function but of its surjectivity. But writing that I realize that one can just restrain the codomain to its image to make my remark more rigorous.